# Azure Mapping Data Flow : Not able to use blob storage dataset as a source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I added a Azure Blob `dataset` as a source to a Azure mapping data flow, but am not able to view the preview as it is showing the below error :

> Dataset is using 'AzureStorage' linked service type, which is not supported in data flow.

Given below is the dataset JSON :

```
{
"name": "PIT_Input",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "data_staging",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "DelimitedText",
    "typeProperties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
            "container": "dataflowpoc"
        },
        "columnDelimiter": ",",
        "escapeChar": "\\",
        "firstRowAsHeader": true,
        "quoteChar": "\""
    },
    "schema": []
  }
}
```

**data_staging** is a linked service of type **Azure Storage**.

The documentation states that Azure Blob datasets can used as a source.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Just an assumption: was a performance option set to: **Premium**? If so, consider to change to **Standard**. Another smaller recommendation is an account kind to set to the most modern "StorageV2"

Comment: Please try creating a new dataset of type Delimited Text with an Azure Blob Linked Service and let me know if you still receive this error.

Comment: I changed the type of the Linked Service from Azure storage to Azure blob storage, and it worked. I'm really not sure about the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According you `dataset` `JSON`, you just choose the container `dataflowpoc`, didn't specify the file.

You only could preview the file data which type is "DelimitedText":
[image]

`Dataset`  Preview data, we can not preview all the data if files in the container with different schema:
[image]

Dataset JSON:

```
{
    "name": "DelimitedText1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "container": "containerleon"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": false,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

But in Data Flow Data Preview, we can see all the data in the files:
[image]

I think your error just happened by accident, please refresh the Data Factory and try again.

**Update:**

The error is solved: "I changed the type of the Linked Service from Azure storage to Azure blob storage, and it worked."

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed the type of the Linked Service from Azure storage to Azure blob storage, and it worked. I'm really not sure about the difference between the two.

Comment: @VishnuSuresh Congratulations. Storage is too widely, it has blog storage, file, queue and table storage. Do mind me update you comment to my answer? Then   
you can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.